# Redirect from a console action in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, redirect, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, console-application

I'm trying to build my first console app using Zend Framework 2, tinkering both with that framework and doctrine, and I was trying to create an action in my controller that would simply "redirect" to another action in the Doctrine module.

I tried doing it like:

```
public function setupAction() {
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('orm:schema-tool:create');
}
```

but I get

> ```
> Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException
> Route with name "orm:schema-tool:create" not found
> ```

however if I call the action `orm:schema-tool:create` directly from command line, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting request to Doctrine's CLI interface, you can easily achieve same effect manually utilizing **SchemaTool**, it doesn't requires too much digging.

For example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractConsoleController;

BarController extends AbstractConsoleController
{
    public function setupAction() {
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($em);
        $metaData = $em->getMetaDataFactory()->getAllMetaData();

        // This will return all SQL queries which needs to run to create schema
        $sql = $schemaTool->getCreateSchemaSql($metaData);

        // This will directly execute that queires.
        $schemaTool->createSchema($metaData);   
    }
}
```

You may also want to inspect other interface methods of [SchemaTool](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php) like [updateSchema()](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php#L833) and [dropSchema()](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php#L725).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks :) still I find it rather strange that you can redirect a standard mvc request and not one from console...

Answer (score 1):

`orm:schema-tool:create` is not a ZF2 route, it's a command you pass to the Doctrine command line script. I'm guessing you don't actually want to redirect, you simply want to run what the doctrine command runs. This might be possible, but would take a bit of digging around in the Doctrine code.

Comment: That digging is exactly what I hoped to avoid! It seems to me that there should be a more natural way to do this...